# Is there a way to add custom speed limits in the Here API?

Tags: here-api

I am planning a mapping application for e-Scooters. These scooters can be difficult to drive on certain surfaces (e.g. wet cobblestone) so I was wondering if there is a way to tell the routing algorithm to rather not use certain areas. This should work similar to the avoidareas-Parameter for normal routing, but not completely blocking a zone but rather gradually increasing the cost to travel through an area.

I only found the custom speed profiles for fleet telematics but they only change the speed per road class.

Comment: Any comments from the downvoters?

Answer (score 1):

IF you are using one of the sdk's. There is a class called the DynamicPenalty which will allow you to add routing penalties to certain road segments.

iOS: https://developer.here.com/documentation/ios-premium/api_reference_jazzy/Classes/NMADynamicPenalty.html

Android: https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/routing/DynamicPenalty.html

Comment: That looks like what I'm looking for. But it's only available on the mobile devices?

Comment: @FooTheBar Yah, I believe it's only available on the SDK. From HERE's point of view, they look at that feature as a real time manipulator. So your company has info that HERE doesn't, therefore you want to penalize certain areas based on that information. This real time adjustment doesn't make sense for non real time routing. Same as how traffic data is only available on the sdk.